# How to find the IP of the terminal who is currently logged in?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, awk

I was able to write a script returning the IP address of the logged in remote user. It goes like this:

```
nslookup `pinky | sed -n '2,2p' | awk '{ print $5}'` | tail -n2 | grep Address |  awk '{ print $2}'
```

However, due to the heavy parsing involved, I can't be certain that it would function flawlessly under all conditions.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the sake of those interested in a similar solution working under **root**, here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TERM_CLI_NAME=`who am i | awk '{print $5}'|sed 's/.\(.*\)./\1/'`
nslookup $TERM_CLI_NAME | tail -n2 | grep Address |  awk '{ print $2}'
```

Comment: Ditch the grep and write `awk '/Address/ { print $2 }'`.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
ip="${SSH_CLIENT/ */}"
```

it's shorter.

On the other hand, I'm not sure what exactly did you mean by `2,2p`. Which remote user do you want? The first on the list?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work when ran as root (returned empty string). The 2,2p is merely a sed operator meant to isolate the 2nd line. And yes the script needs to be modified to identify the corresponding terminal.

Comment: Yes, that what my question was - why the second line? What user you're looking for? The command I've given you should set ip to the remote ip of the currently connected over ssh user, but I'm not sure now it's what you're looking for.

Comment: I su to root and wanted the current user (my ultimate goal is showing the logs excluding actions commited by me)

Comment: It is somewhat tricky to find that out after you `su -`, but I'm afraid your goal is not achievable to the desired level of perfection, anyway.